# How can i create file at external storage(sdcard) in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I try to make 'File Control' app.

I found how to read file, but I can't find how to write file.

I set permission like this.

AndroidManifast.xml

```
    <application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and i call this code in MainActivity.onCreate.

```
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };


    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MODE_PRIVATE);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);
```

I want read and write file, at `/storage/3066-3133/title.txt` . `/storage/3066-3133` is my sdcard path.

read file is work perfectly.

```
    public void readFile() {

        String fileTitle = "title.txt";
        File file = new File("/storage/3066-3133", fileTitle);

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            popupToast("read : " + result);

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            popupToast("no file found");

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            popupToast("read fail");
        }

    }
```

but write code occur exception.
`write Exception: /storage/3066-3133/title.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

```
    public void writeFile() {
        String fileTitle = "title.txt";
        File file = new File("/storage/3066-3133", fileTitle);

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile(); // error!!!!
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
            String str = "      write text     ";
            writer.write(str);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            popupToast("write fail");
        }
    }
```

Plus, I can write file at `/storage/emulated/0/title.txt`. `/storage/emulated/0` is bullt-in external storage path.

I need more permission for sdcard?

or this is problem? First, i create project for target sdk:31. and i change 29 in build.gradle. changing target sdk is not work? Someone tell sdk 30 little changed. but, if this is problem, i can't understand then why 'read' work...

Comment: We have not had read/write filesystem access to arbitrary directories on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) since Android 4.4. Either use methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` on `Context`, or use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) to let the user choose where to put the content.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got `/storage/3066-3133/` by  `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MainActivity.getAppContext(), null);`.
you mean, write file in sdcard is impossible? I saw some apps, they can remove or copy files in sdcard, such as file explorer app.

Comment: "I got /storage/3066-3133/ by ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MainActivity.getAppContext(), null);" -- `getExternalFilesDirs()` will return a directory that is unique to your application. It will not return the root of a removable storage device, such as `/storage/3066-3133/`, unless it is a *very* buggy device. You can write to the locations returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`, including creating subdirectories of those.

Comment: "I saw some apps, they can remove or copy files in sdcard, such as file explorer app" -- pre-installed apps can have rights that apps written by you or I cannot. Third-party file explorer apps will be using things like the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), though even that has limits on Android 11 and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare exactly, it return '/storage/3066-3133/Android/data/com.redwings.testapp/files'. I split that path. I download app in play store, so it may be thrid-party app. I search and tried ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, It looks get permission everytimes for app start. it's right?

Comment: "I split that path" -- do not do that. "It looks get permission everytimes for app start. it's right?" -- that would not be necessary. You can call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` for the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. That will give you durable access to the tree that the user chooses.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I will more search for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @CommonsWare if i update my phone to android 11/12, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE not work?

Comment: There are [certain filesystem directories that the user cannot choose on Android 11 and higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage?hl=en#file-directory-restrictions). This includes the roots of some removable storage volumes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then, higher than 10 has no way to write file in sdcard? It seems very strange...

Comment: "Then, higher than 10 has no way to write file in sdcard?" -- there is no way that I know of to write to *arbitrary, developer-chosen* places on removable storage, or to the root of removable storage.

Comment: On an Android 11 device you can write to any directory the user can choose using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or to any subfolder it creates in those directories or creates in root of micro sd card with that action. So i would say: Full Access.

Comment: On an Android 10 device the user can choose root of removable media: Full Access.

Answer (score 0):

USE

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
> in your manifest along with
>
> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your `<`application`/>`